# ¿Cómo extrair una parte del elemento forEach?

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

Necesito obtener cada celda de una tabla con ForEach.

**1 - Mi tabla**
|-  phone --|- mensaje|
| -----------| --------- |
| 12345678 | test uno |
| 23456789 | test dos |

**2 - El código**

```js
    function executeStatement() {  
        request = new Request("select * from customer", function(err) {  
        if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });  
        var result = "";  
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                result+= column.value + " ";  
              }  
            });  
            console.log(result);  
            result ="";  
        });
```

**3 - Mi duda**
En este punto -- result+= column.value + " ";
quiero guardar en dos variables una para el phone y otra para el message.
var phone = ?
var message = ?

Gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Si guardas de esa forma, en cada iteración las variables se pisan (se sobreescriben). Lo suyo es guardar en una lista los valores de cada columna. Puedes usar un objeto para cada fila y en el mismo una clave por cada nombre de columna, una estructura de este tipo: `{ phone: 'valor', message: 'valor'}`. Por cada fila tendrás un objeto de este estilo. Saludos